# Cannot get blob after taking a certain amount of photos in react native using react-native-vision-camera

Tags: javascript, react-native, caching, react-native-vision-camera

I have an app that takes a photo every 5 seconds. It then uploads the photo to an S3 bucket. Everything works as expected, but after a few photos it fails to fetch the photo blob from the uri.

This is the code I use for the components:

```
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';
import DateTimePicker, {
  DateTimePickerEvent,
} from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker';
import {
  Camera,
  CameraPermissionStatus,
  useCameraDevice,
} from 'react-native-vision-camera';
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import {enqueue, uploadPhoto2} from '../store/slices/queue';
import {PermissionsAndroid, Platform} from 'react-native';

type Props = {};

const DimensionsScreen = (props: Props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [initHour, setInitHour] = useState<Date | undefined>(new Date());
  const [endHour, setEndHour] = useState<Date | undefined>(new Date());
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [hourSelection, setHourSelection] = useState('');
  const [storeName, changeStoreName] = useState('Nueva tienda');
  const [capturing, setCapturing] = useState(false);
  const [initialized, setInitialized] = useState(false);
  const [rollGranted, setRollGranted] = useState(false);
  const {queue, uploading} = useSelector(state => state.queue);

  const [cameraPermission, setCameraPermission] =
    useState<CameraPermissionStatus | null>(null);
  const camera = useRef(null);

  const device = useCameraDevice('back');

  useEffect(() => {
    const getPermission = async () => {
      const permission = await Camera.getCameraPermissionStatus();
      console.log('Permission: ', permission);
      setCameraPermission(permission);
    };

    getPermission();
  }, [device]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('capturing?: ', capturing);
    const takePhotoInterval = setInterval(async () => {
      const currentHour = new Date().getHours();
      console.log(
        `attempt to take photo on hour:  ${currentHour} - (${initHour?.getHours()} - ${endHour?.getHours()})`,
      );
      await takePhotoOnGivenInterval();
    }, 5000);

    return function cleanup() {
      console.log('cleaning up');
      clearInterval(takePhotoInterval);
    };
  }, [capturing, initHour, endHour]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (queue.length > 0) {
      console.log('uploading...');

      dispatch(uploadPhoto2(queue[0]));
    }
  }, [queue]);

  const takePhotoOnGivenInterval = async () => {
    const currentHour = new Date().getHours();
    if (
      capturing &&
      capturing &&
      currentHour >= initHour?.getHours() &&
      currentHour < endHour?.getHours() &&
      initialized
    ) {
      console.log('will now take photo...');
      await takePhoto();
      return;
    }

    console.log('attempt failed');
  };

  const showMode = (type: string) => {
    setHourSelection(type);
    setShow(true);
  };

  const setHour = (event: DateTimePickerEvent, date: Date | undefined) => {
    const currentDate = date;

    hourSelection === 'init'
      ? setInitHour(currentDate)
      : setEndHour(currentDate);
    setShow(false);
  };

  const requestCameraPermission = async () => {
    const newCameraPermission = await Camera.requestCameraPermission();
    console.log('New cam permission: ', newCameraPermission);
  };

  const takePhoto = async () => {
    if (camera.current) {
      try {
        const photo = await camera.current.takePhoto({});
        console.log('photo path: ', photo.path);
        const path = `file://${photo.path}`;

        const date = new Date();
        const imgName = `0${date.getDay()}-0${date.getMonth()}-0${date.getFullYear()}-0${date.getHours()}:0${date.getMinutes()}:0${date.getSeconds()}.jpg`;

        dispatch(
          enqueue({
            path,
            filename: imgName,
            folder: 'subway-persons/' + storeName,
          }),
        );
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    }
  };

  const onInitialized = () => {
    console.log('Camera ready');
    setInitialized(true);
  };

  if (!device) return <Text>Camera not available</Text>;

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.hoursContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.titleText}>{storeName}</Text>
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={changeStoreName}
          value={storeName}
          placeholder="Subway escuela militar"
          style={styles.inputText}
        />
        <Text style={styles.titleText}>Ingrese nombre de la tienda</Text>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.setHoursRow}>
        <View style={styles.hoursContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.storeNameButton}
            onPress={() => showMode('init')}>
            <Text>Hora Inicio</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Text>{initHour?.getHours().toString()}</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.hoursContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.storeNameButton}
            onPress={() => showMode('end')}>
            <Text style={styles.textCenter}>Hora fin</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Text>{endHour?.getHours().toString()}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>

      {cameraPermission && cameraPermission != 'granted' && (
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.storeNameButton}
          onPress={requestCameraPermission}>
          <Text style={styles.textCenter}>Permitir uso de camara</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}

      {show && (
        <DateTimePicker
          testID="dateTimePicker"
          value={hourSelection === 'init' ? initHour : endHour || new Date()}
          mode="time"
          is24Hour={true}
          onChange={setHour}
        />
      )}

      {!rollGranted && (
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.storeNameButton} onPress={grantRoll}>
          <Text style={styles.textCenter}>Permitir acceso a galeria</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}

      {device && camera && (
        <>
          {initialized && (
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.storeNameButton}
              onPress={takePhoto}>
              <Text style={styles.textCenter}>Tomar foto</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}

          <Camera
            key={device.id}
            ref={camera}
            device={device}
            isActive={true}
            photo={true}
            onInitialized={onInitialized}
            style={{width: 100, height: 100}}
          />

          {uploading && <Text>Uploading photo - ({queue.length} left..)</Text>}
        </>
      )}

      {/* <Camera ref={camera} device={device} isActive={true} photo={true} /> */}

      {device && camera && initialized && (
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.storeNameButton}
          onPress={() => setCapturing(!capturing)}>
          <Text style={styles.textCenter}>
            {!capturing ? 'Iniciar Captura' : 'Pausar Captura'}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default DimensionsScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#28425B',
    justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  storeNameButton: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    shadowOpacity: 0.44,
    borderRadius: 40,
    borderColor: 'white',
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    paddingVertical: 4,
  },
  setHoursRow: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
    gap: 30,
  },
  hoursContainer: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  textCenter: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  inputText: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 20,
    marginTop: 20,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
  },
  titleText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: 'white',
  },
});
```

And this is how I fetch the image blob from the cache and then upload the data:

```
import {dequeue, enqueue, setUploading} from './queueSlice';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import * as RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: ''",
  secretAccessKey: '"',
  region: 'us-west-2',
});

const s3 = new AWS.S3();

export const uploadPhoto2 = ({path, filename, folder}) => {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch(setUploading(true));
    // dequeue
    dispatch(dequeue());

    try {
      console.log('pre fetch: ', path);

      const imageResponse = await fetch(path);
      const fileData = await imageResponse.blob();

      console.log(path, filename, folder);

      uploadFileToS3(folder, filename, fileData);
      console.log('file uploaded');

      // delete photo
      await RNFS.unlink(path);
      console.log('File deleted');
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    } finally {
      dispatch(setUploading(false));
    }
  };
};

const uploadFileToS3 = (bucketName, fileName, fileData) => {
  const params = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: fileName,
    Body: fileData,
  };

  console.log('params: ', params);

  return s3.upload(params).promise();
};
```

I thought it could be a problem with the cache space, however still fails when trying to fetch the blob. The output error is:

```
[TypeError: Network request failed]
```

Any help would be much appreciated!